# Renault kangoo 1.5dci smoke

Tags: engine, renault, smoke

I just changed the rings and valve seals on my Renault Kangoo 1.5dci, but the engine is still smoking. In addition, the car doesn't start with the key - you have to add quick start in the air intake or push start it.

I tried replacing the glow plugs and the controller, however, the problem persists.

Comment: What do you mean by "done"?  Just a service or something more major?

Comment: @Chenmunka Per OP: "I meant changing rings Skeeming head and changing valves seals"

Comment: What color smoke is it?  Blue/gray smoke can mean oil burning, while white smoke is mostly moisture, and can be coolant burning.  Black smoke could mean a too rich fuel mixture.  Also, where's the smoke coming out?  Under the hood or out the exhaust?